# How to setup dual routers with shared wifi and port forwarding on second router

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, port-forwarding

My modem/router doesn't allow the port forwarding of certain ports due to a software limitation. So I connected a DD-WRT router to the modem, and setup a DMZ on the modem to the DD-WRT router which then port forwards to my wired devices.

Network diagram - https://i.stack.imgur.com/apk9I.png

However, I want to merge the two wireless networks so that wireless devices switch between the two routers depending on signal strength and allow all devices to be able to connect to each other. Currently, devices connected to modem/router cannot connect to those connected to the DD-WRT router.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you ask is not reasonably possible. Understand,  The role of DD-WRT is to prevent unsolicited communications from the Internet (except for your (1) forwarded port). The 'Modem/Router', it's WiFi, and anything on it's 'LAN' is, so far as DD-WRT is concerned, the Internet. Recommend looking at Access-Points like Ubiquity Unifi AC Lite(business product), or Ubiquity Amplify (consumer product), or Cisco WAP. These are either PoE powered, or Mesh, so might be easier to place for optimal coverage. They also feature single point config, so if multiple APs are needed, configuration is coordinated so they act as single network.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the APs you are recommending will do what I want my second router to currently do, or that what I want is impossible and I should use APs to extend coverage?

Comment: APs do not replace a router. DD-WRT runs on lots of consumer routers. Most such routers are actually three boxes in one.  (a) router/firewall. (b) Ethernet Switch (c) WiFi Access-Point.  Router function: connect two networks (Internet & Local) and control what traffic is allowed to flow between. Also, DHCP, sometimes caching DNS.  Ethernet-Switch: just interconnects wired devices.  AP: connects wireless devices to wired (nothing more). Your question implies you need better coverage, but your 2 wifi are on separate networks. Suggesting you replace the AP function with dedicated APs.

Comment: except: Ubiquity Amplify. Being a consumer product, it is a full solution that would replace your router.